# Drop down menu disappearing on Wordpress Themed Website (Blogolife Theme by WPLOOK)

Tags: css, menu, web

The problem pertains to the following website: http://www.secondchanceconsignmentsale.com/

On the top menu, there is only one drop-down under the Consigner menu item.

It seems to disappear on me immediately when I try to move to a link;  regardless of browser/os/ or machine used.  I cannot find anything wrong with the code that was already implemented with the existing WordPress theme.

If anyone has a clue as to what I have done wrong, or a suggestion, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's a commercial theme; ask here: https://wplook.com/help/

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately I acquired it as a free theme, and I am unable to find any support for it directly from WPLOOK at this time.  My client has no problem purchasing the pro version of the theme itself, if need be, however support for it does not seem to be available from the creators without purchasing one of their other themes first.  I have thoroughly looked through the official support forums for any similar issue (and through other multiple online resources, including this website, and found no answer that actually solves the problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What browser and operating system you use? Most likely problem can occur if you do not use native WordPress nav (Menu Settings-> Theme locations -> WPLOOK Main Navigation)

Comment: That is about as clueless a response as I  have come to expect from Stack Overflow.

I fixed this problem myself months ago (I overlooked the obvious, which is why I wanted a second set of eyes on it).  I've noticed quite a trend on this site to pass the buck on to others, like was done with my question.  Don't take my word for it, the trend is right in front of you.  As far as I am concerned I can no longer recommend Stack Overflow.  Why use it when the talent has obviously graduated.